# How do I prevent a gridscroller from being created in a tree panel?

Tags: extjs

I have the following code which creates an expandable tree panel inside of a tree store. My problem is that with the `autoscroll` true and scroll true I have a scroll bar already.

When I expand a folder in the tree a gridscroll is created and appended to the main container creating two scroll bars side by side.

how can I trap the expanding folder and prevent the grid scroller from being rendered?

I think it is `setAutoScroll(false)` method on the column but I can't figure out how to set it.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false
});
Ext.require(['Ext.form.*', 'Ext.tree.*', 'Ext.grid.*', 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.util.*', 'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager', 'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature', 'Ext.ModelManager']);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('model1', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'text',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'pathInfo',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    });

    storeAddTo = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: 'model1',
        folderSort: true,
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: myJSONTextAddTo
        }
    });

    var treeConfigAddTo = {

        //title: 'Select an existing folder from the list',
        id: 'grid-foldersAddTo',
        width: 320,
        height: 330,
        store: storeAddTo, //
        rootVisible: false,
        useArrows: true,
        singleExpand: false,
        renderTo: 'grid-foldersAddTo',
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            text: 'Folders',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: false,
            dataIndex: 'text',
            filterable: false
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            autoScroll: true,
            scroll: true,
        }
    }

    treeAddTo = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', treeConfigAddTo);

});
```

> data (myJSONTextAddTo)

```
[{
    text: "Cars",
    "pathInfo": "Cars",
    children: [{
        text: "Luxury",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\Luxury\\Bentley",
        children: [{
            text: "Bentley",
            "pathInfo": "Cars\\Luxury\\Bentley",
            children: []
        }, {
            text: "Porsche",
            "pathInfo": "Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche",
            children: [{
                text: "Cars",
                "pathInfo": "Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche\\Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche",
                children: [{
                    text: "Luxury",
                    "pathInfo": "Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche\\Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche",
                    children: [{
                        text: "Porsche",
                        "pathInfo": "Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche\\Cars\\Luxury\\Porsche",
                        children: []
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        text: "Dealers",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\Dealers",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "Ferrari",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\Ferrari",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "Sports",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\Sports",
        children: [{
            text: "Chevy",
            "pathInfo": "Cars\\Sports\\Chevy",
            children: []
        }]
    }, {
        text: "mycar",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\mycar",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "test2",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\test2",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "test3",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\test3",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "test4",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\test4",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "test5",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\test5",
        children: []
    }, {
        text: "test 6",
        "pathInfo": "Cars\\test 6",
        children: [{
            text: "Test 6.1",
            "pathInfo": "Cars\\test 6\\Test 6.1",
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: can you please post the data and model as well, i'll try to help you

Comment: Thank you ! - I have updated the code and posted sample data !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/Qc5XV/ 
I removed the view configs you had and removed the height constraint to allow the tree to grow. I hope that's what you were after. If you wanted to fix the height then uncomment the height config and the tree panel will auto scroll when needed. This seems right to me. You might have other panels surrounding the tree that are giving you problems if so, please let me know the layout and we can troubleshoot it further. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking to time to help with this - I really appreciate it. yes are correct I have other containers. There are many other 1st level folders with CARS and before the "scroll" is triggered when you expand the first level there are so many folders that they pass out of the container and are hidden.

Comment: great idea on the jsfiddle - I will try and make a working example on there. more like this without the initial scrollbar http://jsfiddle.net/mdroden/AjJhK/ - will work on it some more - thanks again

Comment: you are welcome. if you can reproduce the behavior in the fiddle let me know and I can take a look at it. don't forget to use up tick and check buttons to the left of the answer to mark useful and/or answered. Thanks!

Comment: The native style sheet I have to deal with is extremely complicated so I settled for the moment for compromize - start with the > Root collapsed and then when it is expanded the gridscroller is created and everything works. There are 4 containers and they all have some say over the overflowing content - the problem is that they do not work in harmony with each other. I will see how the customer responds and let you know - thanks again Dmitry